# Oracle - How to query 2 tables to create a Columns and Rows

Tags: oracle

Sorry I seem to be having a bit of mental block.

I have a table that looks like this

```
SECTION_ID  |  TITLE
-------------------------
1             Section1
2             Section2
3             Section3
```

and another table like this

```
KPI TITLE   |  SECTION_ID
----------------------------
Title1         1
Title2         1
Title3         2
Title4         3
Title5         3
Title5         3
```

I want to join the two tables so they look like this

```
Section1 | Section2 | Section3
------------------------------
Title1     Title3     Title4
Title2                Title5
                      Title6
```

The number of sections and titles are dynamic so I can't really harcode anything.

Comment: The number of titles is not a problem - their number can be anything, they can be ordered, and nulls can be shown at the bottom. But the number of Sections not being known beforehand is a problem. You can't do this with plain SQL, you need dynamic SQL. For an example (when the number of output columns is known) see for example my solution to this Stack Overflow question (at the bottom of the page): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803771/need-to-arrange-employee-names-as-per-their-city-column-wise/36823614#36823614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done without dynamic SQL or knowing the names of your sections beforehand. If you do know the names, then you can do something similar with a pivot. This doesn't give the exact output you asked for since pivot aggregates data, but depending on what you're trying to accomplish, this may do it for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT T1.TITLE, T2.KPI_TITLE
    FROM T1, T2
    WHERE T1.SECTION_ID = T2.SECTION_ID
)
PIVOT (
    LISTAGG(KPI_TITLE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY KPI_TITLE)
    FOR TITLE IN ('Section1','Section2','Section3')
)
```

The output will be this:

```
Section1        | Section2 | Section3
----------------------------------------------------
Title1, Title2     Title3     Title4, Title5, Title6
```