# How to select row data as column header and arrange the value based on the header in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider i am having one table as Employee_Details where the Employee_Name and Employee_Level is maintained.

**For Example**

[image: Employee_Details]**

Each Employee_Level should be my output column and all the Employee_name should be arranged alphabetically based on the employee_level

Comment: Are the levels fixed? Sounds like you want to pivot, but how depends on which version you're on, and whether it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Yes Levels are fixed and employee name will be added newly with the existing Employee Level.  I am using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing you mentioned your Oracle version (10g in your case) - in most cases that should be included with your question.

This precludes the use of PIVOT - as in the solution provided here: [Need to arrange employee names as per their city column wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803771/need-to-arrange-employee-names-as-per-their-city-column-wise/36823614#36823614)  (however, I provide a "manual" PIVOT solution at the end of this Answer).

An alternative is to use a full outer join, like so. You must be careful with the join condition (notice the use of NVL in the last join condition) due to the iterated full outer join.

```
with
     employee_details ( employee_name, employee_level ) as (
       select 'Vingesh' , 'Manager'           from dual union all
       select 'Ragul'   , 'Senior Manager'    from dual union all
       select 'Nivithen', 'Senior Manager'    from dual union all
       select 'Joe'     , 'Associate Manager' from dual union all
       select 'Arul'    , 'Manager'           from dual union all
       select 'Rishi'   , 'Manager'           from dual
     ),
     prep ( employee_name, employee_level, rn ) as (
       select employee_name, employee_level, 
              row_number() over (partition by employee_level order by employee_name)
       from   employee_details
     )
select p1.employee_name as associate_manager,
       p2.employee_name as manager,
       p3.employee_name as senior_manager
from   (select employee_name, rn from prep where employee_level = 'Associate Manager') p1
       full outer join
       (select employee_name, rn from prep where employee_level = 'Manager')           p2
           on p1.rn = p2.rn
       full outer join
       (select employee_name, rn from prep where employee_level = 'Senior Manager')    p3
           on nvl(p1.rn, p2.rn) = p3.rn
order by 1, 2, 3
;

ASSOCIATE_MANAGER MANAGER           SENIOR_MANAGER
----------------- ----------------- -----------------
Joe               Arul              Nivithen
                  Rishi             Ragul
                  Vingesh

3 rows selected.
```

You could also take the same "prep" factored subquery and replace the iterated full outer join with the select statement below. You may want to try both solutions and see which is faster on your data; the result should be the same.

```
select min(case when employee_level = 'Associate Manager' 
                then employee_name end) as associate_manager,
       min(case when employee_level = 'Manager' 
                then employee_name end) as manager,
       min(case when employee_level = 'Senior Manager' 
                then employee_name end) as senior_manager
from   prep
group by rn
order by 1, 2, 3
;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing both the options. I have taken second option and it solved my problem...